# What is the name of the drum you wear on your back to play without your hands?

Tags: drums, drum-kits, drum-hardware

Is there a type of drum which is intended to be worn on your back and played "hands-free"? If so, what is it called?

I know I've seen this several times in my life, and assumed it was not a custom rig, but, perhaps it is?

Since I don't know what it's called, it's really hard for me to find a picture of one. This is not dissimilar to what I've seen:

[image]

Comment: Ya know  bass drums and high-hats (in a jazz or rock percussionist's setup)  are not played w/ hands, right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a [marching bass drum](https://www.google.gr/search?q=marching+bass+drums&rlz=1C1SKPL_enGR419GR481&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIr8PppLvoxwIVCO5yCh0F6Af4) worn in the back. Something like this:

[image]

As you can see, both the image you provided and the one I did, have these straps that hold the bass drum on the person's torso. The pic you provided has that drum strapped in the back.

The only difference is that it has some kind of mechanism to be played with the foot (?)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of one-off adaptations which allow a street performer to bang a drum, blow a pennywhistle, or do other things based on leg or foot motions.  The usual name for such a fellow is "one-man band."   For all I know you can buy the mallet control linkage at Amazon these days :-) but the photo sure looks home-brewed.